# How to set a hotkey to run a command line?

Tags: command-line, autoit, hotkeys

I want <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to run command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe" -path "F:\something\dir\blah\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per

- [Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) > [Function Reference](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm) > [`HotKeySet()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm) and
- [Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) > [Function Reference](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm) > [`RunWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm) :

```
Global Const $g_sKey = '+{NUMPADADD}', _
             $g_sCmd = FileGetShortName("C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe") & ' -path "F:\something\dir\blah"'

HotKeySet($g_sKey, RunCmd)

While True

    Sleep(0)

WEnd

Func RunCmd()

    RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c ' & $g_sCmd)

EndFunc
```

Comment: May I ask: the ` '+{NUMPADADD}'` is invoked when I hit the regular keyboard + key (not just the numpad)  Is there something I need to do?

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) distinguishes between `{+}` and `{NUMPADADD}`, possibly Windows API doesn't due to SHIFT combination. Could use different modifier key (CTRL instead of SHIFT for example) or post about it [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/) or [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/trac/autoit) (seems out of script's control).